# Native $_POST or $_GET elements

Tags: php, http, rest, post, get

After reading this [tutorial](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) I ran into this `$data = $_POST;` or `$data = $_GET`
and then this is executed `$data['data'];` So I am assuming its either `$_POST['data']` or `$_GET['data']`. This is in the context of a rest api http request.

My question is, where the heck did that `'data'` element come from? Is that some sort of native post or get element? Testing its out with var_dump doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: That tutorial states: *"There are a few ways we could go about doing this, but let’s just assume that we’ll always get a key/value pair in our request: `‘data’ => actual data`. Let’s also assume that the actual data will be JSON."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Data" is a key of the value you have sent to server. For example you can send GET request to your script like this `http://localhost/myscript.php?data=mysuperdatawillbehere`
Or you can send post request by creating form which will be send POST request to your script or by using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or you can install some plugin for your browser to emulate requests. I use [poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) for firefox

Answer (score 1):

All $_POST or $_GET parameters are returned to array !
and users can accessing them by refer the array objects
For example :

```
$_POST --> Array("title" => "value") --> and access it by --> $_POST['title']
```

only that, hope it can help !!

Comment: Thanks for the input but I already know that post and get vars in php are arrays. What I am asking is why is it I see a post array with a `data` element when I did not see it set anywhere. Presumably a post would have to be made to the server with `data = something` in order for it to appear. In the tutorial that is never shown.